# Составить правильный ответ от сервера

Tags: php, json

От сервера получаю ответ вида:

```
{"id":"14","story":[{"name":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"13","story":[{"name":"Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол ","author":"1"}]}
```

А нужно, чтобы ответ был вида:

```
{response: [
{"id":"14","story":[{"name":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","author":"1"}]}
{"id":"13","story":[{"name":"Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол ","author":"1"}]}
]}
```

Вот php код моего ответа:

```
$response = array();
$storyAll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `story` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($storyAll))
{
        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $result["text"];
        $product["author"] = $result["author"];
        $response["id"] = $result["id"];

        $response["story"] = array();

        array_push($response["story"], $product);

        echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Это у вас уже который дубль вопроса?

Comment: @Visman это первый. То были о самом разборе ответа

Answer (score 2):

```
$responseEntries = [];
$storyQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `story` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($storyQuery)) {
    $product = ['name' => $result['text'], 'author' => $result['author'],];
    $responseEntry = ['id' => $result['id'], 'story' => [$product,],];
    $responseEntries[] = $responseEntry;
}

echo json_encode(['response' => $responseEntries]);
```